# Creating Sequential Component Names in Vue/React Without Using Loops or Props

Tags: reactjs, vuejs3

**Problem Description:**

I want to create multiple instances of a React component (`BaseComponent`) without using a `for` loop, `Array.from`, or passing any additional props. Each instance should be sequentially named in the browser as "base-component-1," "base-component-2," and so on. When I add another `<BaseComponent />`, it should increment the naming, e.g., "base-component-4" for the fourth instance.

**Context:**

I have already attempted to create the components using a `for` loop, but I would like to explore alternative solutions that don't rely on loops, Array methods, or additional props.

**Desired Output:**

- Input:

  ```
  <BaseComponent />
  <BaseComponent />
  <BaseComponent />
  <BaseComponent />
  ```
- Output in the browser:

  - `base-component-1`
  - `base-component-2`
  - `base-component-3`
  - `base-component-4`

**Question:**

How can I achieve this naming pattern for sequentially rendering instances of `<BaseComponent>` in React without utilizing a `for` loop, `Array.from`, or passing additional props?

Provide 3 instances of the component without any props:

```
<BaseComponent />
<BaseComponent />
<BaseComponent />
```

In the browser, it will display as follows:

- `base-component-1`
- `base-component-2`
- `base-component-3`

If you add one more `<BaseComponent />`, it will be displayed as `base-component-4`, for example.

When you input 4 components without props:

```
<BaseComponent />
<BaseComponent />
<BaseComponent />
<BaseComponent />
```

The output in the browser will appear like this:

- `base-component-1`
- `base-component-2`
- `base-component-3`
- `base-component-4`

So, how can I achieve this without using a for loop, Array.from, or props?"

Comment: I've seen some vue libraries managed to do that. By keep tracking each one of the component by using global config and hooks. You can see [this piece of code](https://github.com/element-plus/element-plus/blob/dev/packages/hooks/use-z-index/index.ts). But the process is very complex that i'd refrain from doing that